# Fullcalendar not rendering correct

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using the `jQuery` plugin `Fullcalendar` so far I was able to display the data stored in my `MySQL`  Database but it is not displaying the right way. What I mean is:

e.g.:

```
}
    "id":"1","title":"Test",
    "start":"2015-01-28 10:30:00",
    "end":"2015-02-04 12:30:00",
    "url":"",
    "allDay":"false"
}
```

This is one record in my Database. It is supposed to display on my calendar

`2015-01-28 10:30:00`   to  `2015-02-04 12:30:00`.

But it's not. Instead `allDay` is `true`(even if in the database it say `false`) and I need to add an other day to.

e.g.: If I want to display form the 16-03 to 17-03 I need to add an other day -> 16-03 to 18-03 (so that it displays 16-03 to 17-03)

This is my `SELECT` query:

```
<?php
$json = array();

// Query that retrieves events
$querySQL = "SELECT * FROM evenement";
// connection to the database
try {
    $bdd = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=dbcontrol", "root", "");
} catch(Exception $e) {
    exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}
// Execute the query
$result = $bdd->query($querySQL) or die(print_r($bdd->errorInfo()));

// sending the encoded result to success page
    echo json_encode($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
?>
```

And this is my `jQuery`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var currentTime = new Date();
        /* initialize the external events
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#external-events .fc-event').each(function() {

            // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
            $(this).data('event', {
                title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
            });

            // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
            $(this).draggable({
                zIndex: 999,
                revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
            });

        });


        /* initialize the calendar
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: currentTime,
            editable: true,
            droppable: true,

            eventBackgroundColor: '#A80000',
            eventBorderColor: '#A80000',

            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            events: {
                url: './php/select-events.php',
                error: function() {
                    $('#script-warning').show();
                }
            },
            loading: function(bool) {
                $('#loading').toggle(bool);
            }
        });

    });
```

How can I display the records in the right way.

## EDIT:

### Additional question :

How do I prevent `echo json_encode($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));` from displaying my entire `json` on my page.

Screenshot : http://snag.gy/ZyKFa.jpg

Comment: `"allDay": false` is the correct way to set a boolean javascript value.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo json_encode($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

Will always output your json on page. If you whant to hide it you need to wrap it in a container of somekind (javascript variable or div for example). Then hide the container if you use a DOM container.

like this:

```
echo "<script> var myJSON = " . json_encode($result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) . "</script>";
```

This will add a javascript variable conatining your JSON

Comment: When I try to do this, my records disappear

Comment: As were your question... The json is still avalible but as a javascript variable instead.

Comment: Sorry, I explained it wrong. When I try this, my events inside the table disappear too not only the `JSON` records